# AWK: print colums of a matrix using first column as reference

Tags: awk

I want to read first colum in a matrix, and then print columns of this matrix using this first colum as reference. And example:

```
mat.txt
2 10 6 12 3
4 11 1 22 6
5 15 3 18 9
```

Using first column as reference, I would like to get columns 2, 4 and 5, and also put the value of first colum at the begining.

```
2 10 12 3
4 11 22 6
5 15 18 9
```

I try this, but doesn't work well:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{c++;cols[c]=$1;end}
            {for(i=1;i<=c;i++) printf("%s%s",$(cols[i]+1),i<c ? OFS : "\n")}' mat.txt mat.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1;next} {printf "%s ",a[FNR];for (i in a) printf "%s ",$(a[i]);print ""}' mat.txt{,}
2 10 12 3
4 11 22 6
5 15 18 9
```

The `{,}` make the file be used two times.

Comment: Great Jotne!! The a[FNR] do the trick!!! And the {.} was useful as well. Just another question. If was possible to print the a array (the reference) as header (first row) and then the matrix?

Comment: @ManuelRamón if you mean like to print the reference column in first row, you can do: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1;next} FNR==1 {for (i in a) printf "%s ", a[i];print ""} {for (i in a) printf "%s ",$(a[i]);print ""}'`  PS this `<code>a[FNR]</code>` could also be written `<code>a[++j]</code>`